# Internal message system with SQL database

Tags: sql-server, email-server

I was asked to install a -rather basic- Internal message system with SQL database we could integrate with our websites.
A user is logged onto the website and should then be able to go to its Inbox or outbox; of course they should be able to sent to other users. 
Important: It's not a smtp/pop mailserver system I'm looking for!

I found something with similar functionalities with an access DB (also a possibility)
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?lngWId=4&txtCodeId=6859

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a good reason to use an SQL database?  It sounds like you just need a basic ticketing system, of which there are many options but see RT http://bestpractical.com/rt/ for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a bulletin board software (forum) or alike (like phpBB)?
Even if you don't use the forum part, there are still PNs (private notifications) coming with it (usually).

But anyway, we once had to program sth. like that in school. Maybe I'll find it back.

YEAH: http://jeronimo.servehttp.com/jeronimail/public_html/
Unfortunately I don't have the database schema anymore :-(